# How do I tell Android Studio to run assembleDebug and not assembleDebugTest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android Studio (1.1 RC 1), when I run my app from the Run button, the Gradle console tab shows that the last-run task is assembleDebug.

A colleague who is also running Android Studio 1.1 sees that the task is called assembleDebugTest. The test suites then run. He would like to configure Android Studio so that when he hits Run, then assembleDebug runs, but not the tests.

What can we do to change his configuration so that the task that runs is assembleDebug?

Comment: What option is selected in the run configuration drop-down, immediately to the left of the Run button?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @CommonsWare. I had "app", an Android run config. He had a JUnit run config with the test project name.

Comment: Well, that would explain your symptoms. Have the other developer switch to the `app` run configuration, or create it if needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare here's more info about the whole problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777705/how-to-make-android-studio-1-1-call-generatedebugtestsources-instead-of-assemble .. any help appreciated!

Comment: Here is how:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777705/how-to-make-android-studio-1-1-call-generatedebugtestsources-instead-of-assemble