# How to make Android Studio 1.1 call generateDebugTestSources instead of assembleDebugTest during "Make" instruction?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project with 1,000+ tests running fine with Robolectric. After switching to Android Studio 1.1 when I go to "Run" -> "All Tests" during the "Make" instruction Android Studio calls Gradle's assembleDebugTest instead of generateDebugTestSources .. In my case this makes the build system to start dexing and packaging the test APK which is useless for me since all the tests are JVM tests.

I found this [change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea.git/+/9beacde93c5e3d952eb86c1e4b05e005e713091b%5E%21/#F2) that might be causing it:

```
-      if (testCompileType == TestCompileType.ANDROID_TESTS) {
+      if (testCompileType != TestCompileType.NONE) {
         String gradleTaskName = properties.ASSEMBLE_TEST_TASK_NAME;
         if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(gradleTaskName)) {
           tasks.add(createBuildTask(gradlePath, gradleTaskName));
```

Is there a way to make it configurable on Android Studio? Version 1.0 was working fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the new `test` folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "new test folder"? The tests are at src/test/java.

Comment: yeah that is what I mean. Are you using version 1.1.0 of the gradle plugin?

Comment: Yes, both 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in the solution according to the new Unit Testing guide:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

you need to change the test artifacts to "Unit Testing" as describe on step 5. That way when you run all the tests AS will call the new `assembleDebugUnitTest` task instead of `assembleDebugTest`.